# Working on parsing with jsoup. I try to extract text from element without id but it doesn't seems to work

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

[1 of the elements I want to print out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iC7pG.jpg)

This is the link to the site: http://rozklady.mpk.krakow.pl/?lang=PL&rozklad=20180520&linia=1

And this is the code I'm trying to run:

```
package modul_1;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;


public class fetch_bus_stops {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://rozklady.mpk.krakow.pl/?lang=PL&rozklad=20180520&linia=1").userAgent("Mozilla/17.0").get();
            int i=0;
            for(Element row:doc.select("html > body > table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td[2] > table > tbody > tr[2] > td > table > tbody >tr > td[1] > table > tbody > tr[2] > td > table > tbody"))
            {
                i++;
                System.out.println(i+" "+row.select("tr[1]>td[1]>a>span").text());
            }
            }
         catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: And? What happens when you run it? What *did* you expect to happen instead, when you run it?

Comment: I expected the console to print out these names below the marked element including it.

Comment: It's blank, nothing happens.